# Referência relativa em arquivos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, referência

Olá, Comunidade!

Minha dúvida é sobre como funciona a referência a arquivos externos em um arquivo JavaScript também externo. Explico!

Suponhamos que eu tenha três arquivos: `index.php`, `json.php` e `javascript.js` com a seguinte estrutura

```html
/
    index.php
    js/
        javascript.js
    data/
        json.php
```

O arquivo JavaScript tem o seguinte código, referenciando o arquivo `json.php`:

```js
$.getJSON( "../data/json.php", function( data ) {
    //faz alguma coisa aqui
});
```

Agora, se eu incluir o arquivo JavaScript no arquivo `index.php` a referência ao arquivo `json.php` se perde, apesar de estar tecnicamente correto o uso da referência relativa no arquivo `.JS`.

Como isso se explica?

Comment: Humn! Temos um *serial downvoter* por aqui. Eu não me importo que negativem a pergunta, mas pelo menos justifiquem pelo bem do juízo alheio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu passo pelo mesmo problema, criei uma função e coloquei no meu arquivo de script global no projeto.

```
function getHostSite() {
  //identificar inicio do path
  //usada nas chamadas Ajax / jSON
  var Path = location.host;
  var VirtualDirectory;
  if (Path.indexOf("localhost") >= 0 && Path.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
    VirtualDirectory = "";
  }
  else {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var VirtualDir = pathname.split('/');
    VirtualDirectory = VirtualDir[1];
    VirtualDirectory = '/' + VirtualDirectory;
  }
  return location.protocol + "//" + location.host + VirtualDirectory + "/"
}
```

Utilizo ele para chamadas ajax, independente do nível que a URL estiver.

```
url: getHostSite() + "Views/TelaCompras",
```

Comment: você pode explicar melhor o que o código faz?

Comment: é muito simples, ele pega sua URL root, sem diretórios ou rotas.
Assim você não precisa usar o "../data/json" e sim apenas getHostSite() + "data/json", garantindo que funcione, independente do nível que você esteja em sua URL.

Comment: Então, é isso que eu quero!!!

Comment: Testa essa rotina, se ainda tiver problema da um toque!
abraços